# Unable to store value in stack

Tags: javascript

In this code, the `subKeys` has some values which is extract from cookie, the message prompt `cval: 3` but I could not push store each `subKeys` values into `stack` array which is the `stack` is always empty.

```
var stack = new Array();
var temp = document.cookie;

//alert("cookie: "+temp);
function upSelect() {
    temp = temp.replace("tutorSelect=","");
    subKeys=temp.split(",");
    for(var i=0;i<subKeys.length;i++) {
        alert("cval: "+subKeys.length);
        //push to stack?
        stack.push(String(subKeys[i]));
        alert("stack: ",stack.length);
        document.getElementById("t"+subKeys[i]).src="tta/rem.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's the smallest things that bother most. It's the way you try to alert the stack length: instead if `alert("stack: ",stack.length);` (result will be: 'stack: '), use: `alert("stack: "+stack.length);` or `alert(["stack: ",stack.length].join(''))`, or rewrite `alert` so it can receive multiple arguments:

```
window._alert = alert;
window.alert = function(){
  _alert(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(''));
}
```

Comment: ok great that solve it, it's a programming error with actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `temp` has anything in it, that code *will* successfully push onto `stack`. But I think your `alert` may be messed up:

```
alert("stack: ",stack.length);
//             ^--- here
```

You probably wanted a `+` there, `alert` only takes a single argument.

Examples (I started with `temp = "one,two,three"` in case you have no cookies for jsbin.com):

[Your version](http://jsbin.com/edoze3/) (shows `stack:` but no length)

[Working version](http://jsbin.com/edoze3/2) (shows `stack: 1`, then `stack: 2`, then `stack: 3`)